# OnClientClick is working on clicking twice the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have here the `ASP Button`

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 22px" Text="Save" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="ValidateFields();" />
```

And here's the `javascript`

```
  function ValidateFields() {
        if ($("#ctl00_cphCimsNewWindow_ddlChannel").val() == '') {

            $("#ctl00_cphCimsNewWindow_lblErrorIssue").html('This is required');

            return false;

        }
    }
```

But after clicking the button, the text of label becomes empty.
I tried double click, and it works. Why is it happened??

Comment: show html code of this `#ctl00_cphCimsNewWindow_ddlChannel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help but I got the answer by changing my code in `OnClientClick`

```
  OnClientClick="if (!ValidateFields()) {return false;}" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

Comment: You could have used just `return ValidateFields();` in `OnClientClick`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return` in your function call

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 22px" Text="Save" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="return ValidateFields();" />
```

and also return true if your logic satisfies the condition

```
function ValidateFields() {
    if ($("#ctl00_cphCimsNewWindow_ddlChannel").val() == '') {
        $("#ctl00_cphCimsNewWindow_lblErrorIssue").html('This is required');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```